# What is argument type of Xamarin WebView Source?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, webview

I have a WebView that I fully define in the XAML. It displays a "help file" from a local file. It was working for Android with `Source="file:///android_asset/Getting Started Text.html"`. I am now trying to get it to work on UWP also so I added `OnPlatform` as shown below. I am getting:

> XFC0009   No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "Source", or mismatching type between value and property. on the <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Uri">.

I also tried `x:TypeArguments="x:String"` and get the same error. What should the `x:TypeArguments` be for `Webview.Source`?

```
            <WebView  WidthRequest="1000" HeightRequest="1000">
                <WebView.Source>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Uri">
                        <OnPlatform.Platforms>
                            <On Platform="Android" Value="file:///android_asset/Getting Started Text.html" />
                            <On Platform="UWP" Value="ms-appx-web:///Getting Started Text.html" />
                        </OnPlatform.Platforms>
                    </OnPlatform>
                </WebView.Source>
            </WebView>
```

VS 2019 16.9.4 Community on Windows 10 Pro 64. Xamarin 16.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [WebView.Source Property docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.webview.source?view=xamarin-forms) `WebView.Source` is of type `WebViewSource`, so instead of `Uri` or `string` you should put `WebViewSource`:

```
    <WebView WidthRequest="1000"
             HeightRequest="1000">
        <WebView.Source>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="WebViewSource">
                <OnPlatform.Platforms>
                    <On Platform="Android"
                        Value="file:///android_asset/Getting Started Text.html"/>
                    <On Platform="UWP"
                        Value="ms-appx-web:///Getting Started Text.html"/>
                </OnPlatform.Platforms>
            </OnPlatform>
        </WebView.Source>
    </WebView>
```

Comment: My XAML editor (see version above) does not have an x;TypeArgument of WebViewSource. It has HtmlWebViewSource and UrlWebViewSource, both of which give me an error of System.InvalidCastException
  HResult=0x80004002
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Xamarin.Forms.HtmlWebViewSource'.
  Source=Xamarin.Forms.Core in InitializeComponent in the xaml.g.cs code.

Comment: if you mean intelisense doesn't suggest it, it may happen that it works without errors even that it is not suggested , have tried my solution ? if not working you can try `UrlWebViewSource`

Comment: Yes, I did mean that and yes your solution does work. Thank you. ALSO: for anyone reading this in the future, the UWP Value= above is not right; should be just Value="ms-appx-web:///Getting Started Text.html" (no UWP_asset in the path).

Comment: You can edit your question to correct it (uwp value), I will ensure to do he same on my answer, just to confirm it worked with `WebViewSource` or `UrlWebViewSource` ?

Comment: Worked with WebViewSource. UrlWebViewSource gave me the error I cited in my first comment. I will edit my URL.